# Change background color of a cell in matrix visual based on the value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have given sample mock views of a dashboard, and I'm trying to develop it using `PowerBi`, but I'm struggling to implement the below visual.

Image 1 - mock view:

[image: image 1 - mock view]

I tired using Databars conditional formatting but there are few customization options. Is there any method to implement this in powerbi?

Image 2 - data bars:

[image: image 2 - data bars]

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked with **Data bars** option of cell elements section.

Comment: Yes Uday. It navigates to the same customization menu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).